# Manipulate slider in awkward spot

Tags: manipulate, front-end, dynamic, notebooks, display

I'm using Mathematica 12.3 and in this version sliders are placed really awkwardly:

[image]

They are placed to the side instead of on top which makes them take up huge amounts of space. I believe in old versions they used to be on top. Is there a way to make them display on top without too much hassle (otherwise I would have to do that for everytime I use manipulate and I use manipulate a lot)

Code:

```
a = 1;
ω0 = 1.;
ω =.;
t =.;
k[ω_] := 2/a ArcSin[ω/(2 ω0)]
Manipulate[
 Animate[Plot[Re[Exp[I (ω t - k[ω] x)]], {x, 0, 6}, 
   PlotRange -> {-1, 1}], {t, 0, (2 π)/ω}], {{ω, 1}, 0, 3}]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can adjust the `ControlPlacement` option. To avoid setting the option every time, you may add

```
SetOptions[Manipulate, ControlPlacement -> Top]
```

to your `SystemOpen@"init.m"` file.

Comment: Oh wow how did I not find this option. Thanks this is very useful!